# IRC Bouncer connect without /quote pass?

Tags: networking, irc, irc-bouncer

I am using a bouncer (ZNC) to connect to an IRC network. I am using ChatZilla to connect to the bouncer.

On connect I get the following message:

```
You need to send your password. Try /quote PASS <username>:<password>
```

Is there a way I can setup my connection to avoid manually entering the username and password each time? The IRC client does not provide a server password field unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself after quite some searching.
There is the command /name which allows you to set a username beforehand, not in any setting along with the name of the IRC server and password.

So all you need to do, on startup of the IRC client for example,

/name your_username
/server server.com 1234 your_password

In Chatzilla, that would go in to the section:
Global Settings - Lists - Commands to be run when starting Chatzilla.

It's not possible to connect to ZNC with a single command, through the locations settings for example.

Answer (score 0):

You must set your username and password in the server configuration for your local IRC client.

For example, I use weechat. Weechat uses a file called irc.conf.

```
[server]
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.addresses = "example.com/4444"
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.proxy
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.ipv6
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.ssl = on
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.ssl_cert
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.ssl_priorities
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.ssl_dhkey_size
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.ssl_fingerprint
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.ssl_verify = off
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.password = "the_password_i_pass_with_QUOTE"
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.capabilities
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.sasl_mechanism
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.sasl_username
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.sasl_password
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.sasl_key
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.sasl_timeout
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.sasl_fail
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.autoconnect = on
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.autoreconnect
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.autoreconnect_delay
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.nicks
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.username = "the_username_i_pass_with_QUOTE"
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.realname
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.local_hostname
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.command
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.command_delay
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.autojoin
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.autorejoin
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.autorejoin_delay
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.connection_timeout
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.anti_flood_prio_high
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.anti_flood_prio_low
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.away_check
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.away_check_max_nicks
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.default_msg_kick
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.default_msg_part
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.default_msg_quit
name_of_the_server_in_weechat.notify
```